How to remount drive after power loss?
OS is Debian. I have an external hard drive connected to my computer. The computer is on a UPS but I don't have the power supply for the hard drive connected to the UPS. (I want to maximize the run time of the system itself, and don't care if I lose connection to this drive if there is a power outage)
There was recently a power outage of a few seconds and now I want to restore disk functionality. There was zero chance of anything writing to this disk during the power outage, so don't worry about that. Disk uses LUKS.
This is the current state:
Try to umount:
umount /media/my_data
umount: /media/my_data: not mounted.

Try to mount:
mount /dev/mapper/my_data /media/my_data
mount: /media/my_data: /dev/mapper/my_data already mounted or mount point busy.

Check lsof:
lsof /media/my_data

(no output)
Try to luks close:
cryptsetup luksClose my_data
Device my_data is still in use.

Try to luks open:
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb my_data
Device my_data already exists.

Try to luks open to a different name:
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb my_data2
Cannot use device /dev/sdb which is in use (already mapped or mounted).

How do I fix this without rebooting? It's absolutely crucial that no reboot is needed as I'm in the middle of several large and complex projects that would take quite a bit of time to get everything restored within each gui, etc.
I find it hard to believe on a modern Linux system if a USB drive loses power, the only recourse to get it mounted again is to reboot!

If the drive was still mounted / in use, then it should have been re-detected under a different name (sdb -> sdc or similar). Check dmesg, cat /proc/partitions, lsblk, ...

Did you use umount --lazy at some point? That's another way to get in this situation "not mounted yet still mounted".
